# X'val' notation in mysql appears to always evaluate to zero and complains about the value being incorrect

Tags: mariadb

I am convinced I'm overlooking something painfully simple and obvious here ...
I have copied the example from the Hexadecimal Literals page of the MySQL 8.0 manual (here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)

Specifically, halfway down the page, the manual gives the following example:

```
mysql> SET @v1 = X'41';
mysql> SET @v2 = X'41'+0;
mysql> SET @v3 = CAST(X'41' AS UNSIGNED);
mysql> SELECT @v1, @v2, @v3;
+------+------+------+
| @v1  | @v2  | @v3  |
+------+------+------+
| A    |   65 |   65 |
+------+------+------+
```

However, when I use the example, verbatim, I get the following output (I've switched on warnings so you can see what's happening):

```
MariaDB> \W
Show warnings enabled.
MariaDB> SET @v1 = X'41';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB> SET @v2 = X'41'+0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'A'
MariaDB> SET @v3=CAST(X'41' AS UNSIGNED);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'A'
MariaDB> SELECT @v1, @v2, @v3;
+------+------+------+
| @v1  | @v2  | @v3  |
+------+------+------+
| A    |    0 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if it helps you see what might be incorrect with my setup:

```
MariaDB> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_general_ci   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Clearly it's not happy with me, I assume there's something I haven't done that I should have done, but I have no idea what.

I am using:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

EDIT: (More info).  I wondered if the problem was related to the MariaDB client, however the problem persists when I call MySQL from PHP.  Example:

```
\core\report($this->query("SELECT X'41'+0")->toArray()); //report() and toArray() are my own functions.
```

produces the following output in my log file:

```
object(stdClass)#23 (1) {
    ["X'41'+0"]=>
    string(1) "0"                     <--- Still 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is not MySQL, so you have to check the manual of MariaDB. See the chapter of [hexadecimal literals](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/hexadecimal-literals/#differences-between-mariadb-and-mysql), specially the sub chapter [Differences Between MariaDB and MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/hexadecimal-literals/#differences-between-mariadb-and-mysql), where this behavior is defined:

> ### Differences Between MariaDB and MySQL
>
> ```
> SELECT x'0a'+0;
> +---------+
> | x'0a'+0 |
> +---------+
> |       0 |
> +---------+
> 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x0A'
>
> SELECT X'0a'+0;
> +---------+
> | X'0a'+0 |
> +---------+
> |       0 |
> +---------+
> 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x0A'
>
> SELECT 0x0a+0;
> +--------+
> | 0x0a+0 |
> +--------+
> |     10 |
> +--------+
> ```
>
> In MySQL (up until at least MySQL 8.0.26):
>
> ```
> SELECT x'0a'+0;
> +---------+
> | x'0a'+0 |
> +---------+
> |      10 |
> +---------+
>
> SELECT X'0a'+0;
> +---------+
> | X'0a'+0 |
> +---------+
> |      10 |
> +---------+
>
> SELECT 0x0a+0;
> +--------+
> | 0x0a+0 |
> +--------+
> |     10 |
> +--------+
> ```